# tensorflow, my DQN FlappyBird agent does relatively well in training but after i load the trained model after the session, it is awful

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, artificial-intelligence, reinforcement-learning

My deep Q learning for flappy bird code is as follows:

```
import gym_ple
import gym
import os
import numpy as np
import cv2
from collections import deque
from datetime import datetime
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Conv2D, Flatten, InputLayer, MaxPooling2D, Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import TensorBoard



gym_ple.main(200)
tf.compat.v1.enable_eager_execution()
env = gym.make('FlappyBird-v0') # ações: 1 nada; 0 pula
imagens = []


## Processamento da imagem
def image_processing(image):
    if np.count_nonzero(image) != 0:
        img = cv2.resize(image[:-100,50:,1],dsize=(30,51)) #pegamos somente a paleta verde de cores, recortamos a imagem e a redimensionamos
        return img/255

    else:
        return np.zeros((51,30))

## Aglomerar frames
def frame_stack(stacked_frames, state, is_new, n_stack):
    frame = image_processing(state)
    if is_new:
        stacked_frames = deque([np.zeros(frame.shape, dtype = int) for f in range(n_stack)], maxlen=n_stack)
        for f in range(n_stack):
            stacked_frames.append(frame)
        stacked_state = np.stack(stacked_frames, axis=2)
    else:
        stacked_frames.append(frame)
        stacked_state = np.stack(stacked_frames, axis=2)
    return stacked_state, stacked_frames

class Memory:
    def __init__(self,max_size):
        self.buffer = deque(maxlen = max_size)

    def add(self, experience):
        self.buffer.append(experience)

    def sample(self, batch_size):
        buffer_size = len(self.buffer)
        index = np.random.choice(range(buffer_size),batch_size,replace=False)
        return [self.buffer[i] for i in index]


class DQN:
    def __init__(self, lr, gamma, max_experiences, batch_size, memory,
                 input_dims=[51,30,4],actions=np.array([0,1])):

        self.memory = memory
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.actions = actions
        self.max_experiences = max_experiences
        self.num_actions = len(actions)
        self.input_dims = input_dims
        self.gamma = gamma
        self.lr = lr

        self.model = tf.keras.Sequential([
            InputLayer(input_shape=input_dims),
            Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(7,7), activation='relu'),
            MaxPooling2D(),
            Dropout(0.2),
            Conv2D(96, kernel_size=3, strides=2, activation='relu'),
            MaxPooling2D(),
            Dropout(0.2),
            Conv2D(128, kernel_size=2, strides=1, activation='relu'),
            Dropout(0.2),
            Flatten(),
            Dense(128, activation='linear'),
            Dense(64, activation='linear'),
            Dense(32, activation='linear'),
            Dense(len(actions), activation='linear')])

        self.model.compile(loss = 'mean_squared_error',
                           optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=self.lr),
                           metrics=['accuracy'])


    def act(self, s, episode_actions, actions=np.array([0,1]), prob_cair=70, 
            exploration=0.5, decay=0.999):
        if exploration < 0.01:
            exploration = 0.01
        if np.random.rand() < exploration:
            probs = [actions[1]]*prob_cair + [actions[0]]*(100-prob_cair)
            action = probs[np.random.randint(0,len(probs))]
        else:
            action = np.argmax(self.model.predict(s))
            action = tf.math.reduce_sum(action * tf.one_hot(self.actions, len(self.actions)), axis=1)
            action = np.array(action,dtype=int)[0]
            episode_actions.append(action)
        return action, episode_actions

    def train(self, TargetNet, cb):
        batch = self.memory.sample(self.batch_size)
        states = np.array([each[0] for each in batch], ndmin=3)
        next_states = np.array([each[3] for each in batch], ndmin=3)

        Qs_list = self.model.predict(states)
        Qs2_list = TargetNet.model.predict(next_states)

        X = []
        Y = []

        for index, (s, action , reward, s2, done) in enumerate(batch):

            if not done:
                max_future_q = np.max(Qs2_list[index])
                new_q = reward + self.gamma*max_future_q
            else:
                new_q = reward

            Qs = Qs_list[index]
            Qs[action] = new_q

            X.append(s)
            Y.append(Qs)       

        self.model.fit(x = np.array(X),
                       y = np.array(Y),
                       epochs = 1,
                       callbacks=cb,
                       verbose = 0)

    def copy_weights(self, TrainNet):
        TrainNet.model.set_weights(self.model.get_weights()) 





def main(training=True,
         render=False,
         lr=0.00025,
         gamma=0.99,
         batch_size=96,
         max_size=100000,
         n_stack=4,
         actions=[0,1],
         exploration = 1,
         nepisodes=50,
         npretrain=1000,
         max_steps=50000,
         load_path=''
         ):
    states_size=[51,30,n_stack]
    n_acoes = len(actions)
    ###SET UP DEEP Q NETWORK AND MEMORY
    memory = Memory(100000)
    TrainNet = DQN(lr, gamma,  100, batch_size, memory=memory, input_dims=states_size)
    TargetNet = DQN(lr, gamma, 100, batch_size, memory=memory, input_dims=states_size)

    ### TREINO
    if training:
        #checkpoint_path+=datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")

            ### PRÉPOPULANDO A MEMÓRIA
        s = env.reset()
        s, stacked_frames = frame_stack(None, s, True, n_stack)
        for i in range(npretrain):
            action = actions[np.random.randint(0,n_acoes)]
            s2, reward, done, _ = env.step(action)
            if reward > 0:
                reward*=10
            else:
                reward/5
            s2, stacked_frames = frame_stack(stacked_frames, s2, False, n_stack)
            if done:
                s2=np.zeros(s2.shape)
                memory.add((s,action,reward,s2,done))
                s = env.reset()
                s, stacked_frames = frame_stack(None, s, True, n_stack)
            else:
                memory.add((s, action, reward, s2, done))
                s = s2

        ### INÍCIO DO TREINO
        for episode in range(nepisodes):
            if episode == 49 or episode == 50:
                print(TrainNet.model.get_weights())                
            episode_actions = []
            exploration *= np.power(0.01, 2/(nepisodes*1))
            step=0
            episode_rewards=[]
            s=env.reset()
            s,stacked_frames=frame_stack(None,s,True,n_stack)

            while step<max_steps:
                action, episode_actions = TrainNet.act(np.array(s,ndmin=4), episode_actions, exploration= exploration)
                s2, reward, done, _ = env.step(action)
                if reward>0:
                    reward += 5
                if render:
                    env.render(mode='human')
                episode_rewards.append(reward)
                if done:
                    step=max_steps #sair do laço da linha 174
                    s2 = np.zeros(s2.shape)
                    s2, stacked_frames = frame_stack(None, s2, True, n_stack)
                    total_reward=sum(episode_rewards)
                    desc = np.count_nonzero(episode_actions)
                    sub = len(episode_actions) - desc
                    print(f'Episode::{episode},Rewards::{(total_reward):.2f},Probability of exploration::{(exploration):.4f}, Subiu {sub} vezes e desceu {desc} vezes')
                    memory.add((s,action,reward,s2,done))
                    TargetNet.copy_weights(TrainNet)
                else:

                    s2, stacked_frames = frame_stack(stacked_frames, s2, False, n_stack)
                    memory.add((s,action,reward,s2,done))
                    s = s2
                step+=1

                ### APRENDIZADO PROPRIAMENTE DITO
                TrainNet.train(TargetNet, None)



            if episode%10==0:
                TrainNet.model.save('treino/modelo.h5')
            if episode%100==0 and episode!=0:
                os.mkdir(f'treino/{episode}/')
                TrainNet.model.save(f'treino/{episode}/modelo.h5')
    else:
        TrainNet.model = tf.keras.models.load_model('treino/modelo.h5')
        for episode in range(10):
            s = env.reset()
            s, stacked_frames = frame_stack(None, s, True, n_stack)
            episode_rewards = []
            episode_actions = []
            igual = '='

            print("****************************************************")
            print("EPISODE ", episode)

            done = False
            while not done:

                action = np.argmax(TrainNet.model.predict(np.array(s,ndmin=4)))
                print(s, action)
                episode_actions.append(action)
                s2, reward, done, _ = env.step(action)

                episode_rewards.append(reward)
                env.render(mode='human')
                descidas = np.count_nonzero(episode_actions)*100//len(episode_actions)  ## Obtém cada ação do modelo e printa
                subidas = (len(episode_actions) - descidas)*100//len(episode_actions)   ## como um gráfico de barras

                s2, stack_frames = frame_stack(stacked_frames, s2, False, n_stack)
                s = s2

            print(f'Score     || {sum(episode_rewards)}')
            print(f'Subidas   || {igual*subidas}')
            print(f'Descidas  || {igual*descidas}')




if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(False,False)
    env.close()
```

however, when i set main to main(False, False) after a training session, the agent only goes up/down to every state, always dying. But in the training logs I can clearly see that he is often going through one or two pipes.

for this code i used the open-ai gym environment for flappy bird. For it to run, the package "gym_ple" needs to be installed on the machine. This gym environment gives the agent as a state the frame from the game. The agent has two moves: 0 to fly or 1 to do nothing. I am still refining this script, so that's why it might look so rough.

[Training Rewards](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iMJmJ.jpg)

[Testing Rewards](https://i.stack.imgur.com/opcE8.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

At the very end of your `main()` function, you have a typo in the line `s2, stack_frames = frame_stack(stacked_frames, s2, False, n_stack)`. You have `stack_frames` instead of `stacked_frames` which results in your model never getting the updated `stacked_frames`.